# 'C:\Users\Black' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: asp.net

I have just installed ASP.NET 5 RC-1 Version on Windows 7 Ultimate.
I have project name MvcMovie
and then I ran the comand below

```
D:\Projects\MvcMovie\src\MvcMovie>dnvm list
```

This is the result

```
Active Version           Runtime Architecture OperatingSystem Alias
------ -------           ------- ------------ --------------- -----
       1.0.0-rc1-update1 clr     x86          win


'C:\Users\Black' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

I dont understand why I get the above error.

Then I want to run dnvm use... as below

```
D:\Projects\MvcMovie\src\MvcMovie>dnvm use 1.0.0-rc1-update1
```

But then I got this error

```
Adding C:\Users\Black Fujitsu\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1\bi
n to process PATH
'C:\Users\Black' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
The system cannot find the path specified.
D:\Projects\MvcMovie\src\MvcMovie>
```

Comment: The space is breaking your path

Comment: See here for a potential fix: https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/3234

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your user name has a space in it as does mine.  This is confirmed here:

https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/371

I am running VS 2015 Enterprise Update 1 with ASP.NET 5 RC 1 on Windows 10 Pro Build 1151. I have a user name with a space in it. I am getting the following error when attempting to run dnvm from the command line:

```
Get-Help : Get-Help could not find dnvm - Copy.cmd in a help file in this session. To download updated help topics type
: "Update-Help". To get help online, search for the help topic in the TechNet library at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink
/?LinkID=107116.
At C:\Users\Wayne Blackmon.dnx\bin\dnvm.ps1:998 char:26

$h = Get-Help $_.Name -ShowWindow:$false
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
CategoryInfo : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [Get-Help], HelpNotFoundException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : HelpNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetHelpCommand
Copy.cmd ForEach-Object : You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At C:\Users\Wayne Blackmon.dnx\bin\dnvm.ps1:994 char:13
ForEach-Object {
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [ForEach-Object], RuntimeException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ForEachObjectCommand
The system cannot find the path specified.
'C:\Users\User' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
The system cannot find the path specified.
C:\Users\User Name>
```

And I get the following error when I attempt to run 'dnx run' from the command line

```
'dnx' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I just ran `dnvm install` latest in PowerShell with no error. Then I ran `dnvm list` also without errors. However, I do get path errors when I run the same commands from a windows command prompt. I have confirmed that this does work when run in PowerShell. **The solution is to use PowerShell when accessing dnvm and dnx from a command line.** I have also confirmed that `dnx run` does work in Powershell. For now, use PowerShell if your windows user name has a space in it when accessing dnvm until this issue is fixed.